# non-greedy behavior with multiline and dotall

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string, where I try to match a string from the corresponding 'foo' to either 'bar=1', 'bar=2' or 'bar=3'. So only one match at a time.

```
file_header

foo lorem ipsum \pope
24 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit
Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non 
gnu blu bar=1

foo lorem ipsum \
@>@!@ consectetur adipisici elit
gnu blu bar=2
foo lorem ipsum
23 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit
gnu blu bar=3

foo ... etc
```

I tried everything, from a simple `^foo.*?bar=2$` to something like `^(?!\bfoo\b.*\bfoo\b).*\bfoo\b.*bar=2$`. But with multiline and dotall activated, it will always match the first 'foo' or even mark the whole file header. :(

It seems like a non-greedy behavior is not possible, while using multiline and dotall.

Comment: So, looking for something like [`^foo(?:(?!^foo|bar=2$).)*bar=2$`](https://regex101.com/r/xM4sX9/1)?

Comment: 1) Are you trying to **match** or **search**? 2) Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates your error. Saying "I've tried everything" isn't nearly as useful as you think. Instead, show us, in a **complete** program, one particular thing you've tried. See [mcve] for more information about asking questions that generate excellent answers.

Comment: @Robᵩ I was just experimenting on http://pythex.org/ and don't have any python code yet. That's why I wasn't aware that there is a difference between match and search. (I need the search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tempered greedy token like

```
^foo(?:(?!^foo|bar=2$).)*bar=2$
```

The `(?:(?!^foo|bar=2$).)*` matches any text that is not `foo` (at the beginning of a line/string) and not `bar=2` at the end of the line/string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xM4sX9/1). However, such a construct is resource consuming, it is advised to unroll it. Here is an option:

```
^foo[^\nb]*(?:\n(?!foo)[^\nb]*|b(?!ar$)[^\nb]*)*bar=2$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/xM4sX9/2).

Comment: Wiktor, you are a beast! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Lazy does not always return the shortest match.

Answer (score 1):

This program finds all non-overlapping occurences of `foo <stuff> bar=<number>`. Note the successful use of the non-greedy operator in `re.MULTILINE`-mode using this expression: `^foo.*?bar=\d+$`

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

data = '''
file_header

foo lorem ipsum \pope
24 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit
Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non 
gnu blu bar=1

foo lorem ipsum \
@>@!@ consectetur adipisici elit
gnu blu bar=2
foo lorem ipsum
23 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit
gnu blu bar=3
'''

matches = re.findall(r'^foo.*?bar=\d+$', data, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
pprint (matches)
```

Result:

```
['foo lorem ipsum \\pope\n24 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit\nExcepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non \ngnu blu bar=1',
 'foo lorem ipsum @>@!@ consectetur adipisici elit\ngnu blu bar=2',
 'foo lorem ipsum\n23 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit\ngnu blu bar=3']
```

Comment: Note that this works because the data is nicely organized with a matched foo to a bar. This won't work to get the inner foo to bar if there can be nested foo/bars, or even if bar is a specific set, i.e. [234].

Comment: It seems like this only works, because `re.findall(...)` "returns all non-overlapping matches", so it works consuming. The same code with `re.search(r'^foo.*?bar=3+$', ...` and `print matches.group(0)` returns a string from the first foo to the last bar. Unfortunately that's not what I needed. I'll provide a better example of what I need next time, since my English isn't the best. :D

Answer (score 1):

## Greediness works from left to right

It has nothing to do with `MULTILINE` or `DOTALL`, it is that non-greedy operator
only affects the end of the match, not the start.

To fullfill your desire, add `.*` in front of your pattern.

```
>>> re.findall(r'.*(foo.*?bar=1)', s, re.DOTALL)
['foo lorem ipsum \\pope\n24 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit\nExcepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non \ngnu blu bar=1']
>>> re.findall(r'.*(foo.*?bar=2)', s, re.DOTALL)
['foo lorem ipsum @>@!@ consectetur adipisici elit\ngnu blu bar=2']
>>> re.findall(r'.*(foo.*?bar=3)', s, re.DOTALL)
['foo lorem ipsum\n23 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit\ngnu blu bar=3']
```